# change compFn, multcompBoxplot in multcompView

Tags: r

I ran into a little problem when using the `multcompBoxplot` function in `multocompView`. The following code runs perfectly fine:

```
set.seed(1000)
Data<-c(runif(20, min=0, max=0.4), runif(20, min=0.1, max=0.6), runif(20, min=0.2, max=1))
Names<-c(rep("Type.1", 20), rep("Type.2", 20), rep("Type.3", 20))
Data<-cbind.data.frame(Data, Names, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Data[,2]<-as.factor(Data[,2])
colnames(Data)<-c("Success", "Type")

boxplot(Success~Type, data=Data)

library(multcompView)
multcompBoxplot(Success~Type, data=Data)
```

However, this is using the default setting for `compFn` which is "TukeyHSD". My p-values would come from another function. According to the manual, `compFn` is

> a function whose output will serve as the the only non-default input
>   to either ’multcompTs’ or ’multcompLetters’. The default "TukeyHSD"
>   actually translates to ’TukeyHSD(aov(formula, data))[[1]][, "p adj"]’.

So, `TukeyHSD(aov(formula, data))[[1]][, "p adj"]` returns a vector with p-values for each possible pairwise comparisons. Those p-values, which I have formatted exactly alike from another source are then passed to `multcompLetters` and `multcompTS` for the respective calculations of those functions. If I just do this manually, everything works fine:

```
P.Adj<-TukeyHSD(aov(Success~Type, data=Data))[[1]][, "p adj"]
Species.Groups<-multcompLetters(P.Adj, threshold=0.05)
Species.T<-multcompTs(P.Adj, threshold=0.05)
```

But as soon as I try to provide the exactly same information within `multcompBoxplot`, I get warnings and a broken output displaying neither the T's nor the letters:

```
multcompBoxplot(Success~Type, data=Data, compFn=P.Adj)

Error in do.call(Fn, list(formula = formula, data = data)) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (compFn == "TukeyHSD") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (compFn == "kruskalmc") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

As I understand the manual, this should provide exactly the data the function needs. So does `multcompBoxplot` simply not work with providing the results instead of the function to calculate them, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gowing through the source-code for `multcompBoxplot` I figured it out. The follwoing works:

```
Test.Function<-function(formula, data){TukeyHSD(aov(formula, data))[[1]][, "p adj"]}
multcompBoxplot(Success~Type, data=Data, compFn="Test.Function")
```